# SCOM Error 26319 The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Tags: sql-server, scom

We are frequently receiving this error on SCOM Management server and we are not able to perform any tasks from OM Console.

We have checked our OM Database and SQL Server is performing fine and no issues reported there.

SCOM Version - SCOM 2019 UR1

An exception was thrown while processing SubmitTasks for session ID uuid:2b45a189-343f-455d-b233-e9ab7c0a4d23;id=298.
Exception message: The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.
Full Exception: The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you have a recursive CTE somewhere that's recursing more than 100 levels deep.

Comment: Yes.. but its from SCOM Tool, we are not sure which query does this and there is no information regarding this ....

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarity, it seems you also asked this on the Microsoft Forums and was able to get a response:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/496040/scom-26319-errors.html

**XinGuo-MSFT** 
Hi,

According to this error, it seems that the execution of SQL recursive query exceed the maximum range.

To troubleshoot this problem, we could use the SQL Server Profiler 17 to capture the command that reported this error, and try to manual execute it to see the result. Then use the OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000) increase this range to see the result.

[image: SQL Profiler Options]